# How to skip error and continue processing stream

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Let's assume that I have stream:

```
final Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable
    .fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .map(i -> {
          if (i % 3 == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Haha");
          } else {
            return i;
          }
        }
    );
```

As you can see I may receive some unexpected exception.

How to implement solution which skip exception/error and keep receiving next elements so my target subscriber would be able to see in this particular case:

```
1, 2, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing like `.continueNextIfError`. When the source stream emits an error, it means the stream has terminated and there won't be any additional event.   There is no way to recover or continue the stream after this point.

If the application is correctly designed, usually there is no need to worry about this kind of cases because there is a trivial solution to your problem: just handle the error before it reaches downstream.

```
final Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable
    .fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .map(i -> {
        try {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Haha");
            } else {
                return i;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    )
    .filter(i -> i >= 0);


// or flatMaps cases
final Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable
    .fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .flatMapMaybe(i -> {
        return Maybe.fromCallable(() -> {
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Haha");
                } else {
                    return i;
                }
            })
            .onErrorComplete();
    });
```

Additionally, if the source observable is a cold observable then re-subscribing using `.retry` may help.

Comment: That is sad what you wrote : ```When the source stream emits an error, it means the stream has terminated and there won't be any additional event. There is no way to recover or continue the stream after this point.``` Are you sure that there is no way to recover after such unexpected exception?

Comment: I think it is intentionally designed such way. If you can show some concrete example where continued stream is needed then I think we should be able to find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

You can move "dangerous" code to "child" stream, which in case of error return no elements:

```
   Observable
        .fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        .flatMap(ii -> Observable.just(ii).map(i -> {
                    if (i % 3 == 0) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Haha");
                    } else {
                        return i;
                    }
                }).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
        )
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I like this solution, please check what I found.

Answer (score 0):

For education reason I found solution which may solve this problem.

```
Observable
    .fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .concatMapDelayError(i -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Haha");
      } else {
        return i;
      }
    }))
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
    .subscribe(
        System.out::println,
        throwable -> log.error("That escalated quickly", throwable));
```

The result of above code is (which is what is expected):

```
1
2
4
5
```

Probably there would be problem with infinite stream (worth to check).

Comment: `onErrorResumeNext` triggers on error emission, so this doesn't prevent errors bufferring. Result error - composite exception with collected errors, so yes, here problem with infinity stream.